# fetch data from db and display fk wise data in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

this is my query :

```
SELECT *,wms_master.master_id as masters_id,wms_master.master_head_name as masters_head_name,wms_sub_master.sub_master_id as sub_masters_id,
         wms_sub_master.sub_master_name as sub_masters_name FROM `wms_project_phases`
INNER JOIN wms_sub_master on wms_sub_master.sub_master_id=wms_project_phases.sub_master_id
INNER JOIN wms_master on wms_master.master_id= wms_sub_master.master_id
```

i want to use ajax for displaying the sub_master_id,sub_master_name which is serially master_id,master_name

Answer (score 1):

You need to have some server side component that takes HTTP request from your AJAX function to query the database and produce the required response in order you require and then return it as HTTP response.

NOTE: There are many option available to write server side modules example PHP,.NET etc.